# Jsx concatenation using template literal string in filter and map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

What should I do to correct below code?

```
<p>
{ads.filter(obj => obj._id === this.state.selectedAd_Id)
.map(obj =>obj.expiry_date
&& 
`You have to complete this task in${fromNow(moment(obj.expiry_date))}` )}
</p>
```

this is working

```
<p>
{ads.filter(obj => obj._id === this.state.selectedAd_Id)
.map(obj => obj.expiry_date
&& fromNow(moment(obj.expiry_date)) )}
</p>
```

But how can I concat `You have to complete this task in` when `obj.expiry_date` is not `null`?

Comment: what is the issue with first code is it throwing any error?

Comment: @MayankShukla Objects are not valid as a React child

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return a ternary and use template literal string interpolation with es6.

```
ads.filter(obj => obj._id === this.state.selectedAd_Id)
   .map(obj => obj.expiry_date ? `You have to complete this task in ${fromNow(moment(obj.expiry_date))}` : false)
```

Comment: why && is not working here? just because map has to return true or false?

Answer (score 0):

`obj.expiry_date || ''` will probably do the job

You can also use a [conditional (ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) `obj.expiry_date ? obj.expiry_date : ''`

Comment: `||` is a logical or, `&&` is a logical and.

Check the documentation about [logical operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR)